# POSTGIS - line intersection with modified width

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a given line, and I want to see if a point intersects the line with an increased width boundary.

Is there a functions that does that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd see if a geometry is within a specified distance of another using [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). You could alternatively buffer the line to a polygon and see if the point intersects the buffered polygon, but this is not encouraged as an optimal strategy as it is often an unnecessary computing expense.

So in your case, if a point is within a certain distance of a line use something like:

```
SELECT pt.*, ST_Distance(pt.geom, ln.geom)
FROM lines ln, points pt
WHERE ln.id = 'given line' AND ST_DWithin(ln.geom, pt.geom, width)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(pt.geom, ln.geom)
```